# Order results based on select options? Like 'best match', 'time ending soonest', etc. Using django 1.3

Tags: jquery, python, django, session, select

You know the select options like on ebay where they have 'best match', 'time ending soonest', etc.  And when you choose an option the pages refreshes and returns the results in that order.  How do you do that?

So far this is my idea, I was going to store a session variable for the user and base on what the session variable is upon each refresh/http request, I could determine what the user wants.  So I've got the session variable read/write down on the python/django side, but I have no idea how to set the session variable on the user side, say with jquery or something cuz I was thinking when the user selects an option, jquery sets the session variable and does a refresh, which is picked up by my django view which returns the correct sorted results.

I'm not sure (and it probably isn't) the best way to do this, so please help me out.  Is there a better way of doing this and/or how do you do the client side of my idea?

Thanks !!!

Comment: You could always set a cookie via JavaScript to hold the value instead of putting it into session. You could also make a form and view to set the cookie in case JavaScript isn't available or disabled.

Comment: how would i submit the form from the client side without a submit button?

Comment: You can submit the form from the onChange event of the select, and hide a submit button in a <noscript> for non-JavaScript enabled browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the ordering via `GET`. The template would have something like

```
<a href="?ordering=best">Best match</a>
<a href="?ordering=soonest">Ending soonest</a>
```

The view would check `request.GET` and sort appropriately.

Comment: yea this works but 1) it looks kind of ugly in the address bar and 2) i want the value to be stored so when the user goes from page to page, he/she doesn't have to reselect the option

Comment: I ended up using javascript/jquery to upon select to refresh and store data in cookie and use view to read cookie,  although this answer really wasn't what i was looking for, i'm gonna accept to end this question